# Transaction-Read-Only on Database vs Transactional(readOnly=true) on Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, transactions

I'm a Spring developer and I generally use `@Transactional(readOnly = true)` for read operations. I believe that it is a hint on Hibernate but I don't know how Hibernate send this hint to the database such as Mysql.

And Mysql has read-only-transaction like https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-performance-ro-txn.html

**For Performance**: Hibernate uses this hint for performance (dirty-check) on hibernate level.

**Question**: Does Hibernate send this hint to the MySQL? And Does `@Transactional(readOnly = true)` mean read-only-transaction on Mysql?

Answer (score 0):

Quick response :

- Does Hibernate send this hint to the MySQL?  **No**.
- Does @Transactional(readOnly = true) mean read-only-transaction ? **Yes**,

Explanation:

@transactional(readOnly=true) means that spring will prevent you from modifying on database (write, update, delete..).
this control is implemented at the spring project level (and not on database level).

**How does @Transactional works :**

*@Transactional* utilizes Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP) to proxy the annotated class or method. Aspects such as **TransactionInterceptor.class** and **TransactionAspectSupport.class** intercept the method calls and apply the specified control (such as readOnly, for example), creates transaction , commit or rollback

I recommand this article on Transaction Management made by me On LinkedIn :
https://www.linkedin.com/posts/youness-tizi-30517a133_spring-springabrjdbc-transactions-activity-7167899616141651969-ZP-g?utm_source=share&utm_medium=member_desktop